# Add to file only new lines/new data

Tags: shell-script, logs

I need to make a real time file with IP addresses which request some of my website/url.
At this moment I grep apache access log and get only ip, then sort and delete duplicates, then save to ip.txt file.
All is good until apache make logroate, then all previous IPs from ip.txt disappear, and we start from 0 (until apache logs collect new data).

My question is, how to make to add only new data to file, previous data don't touch?

Something like collect info as I said on top to ip.txt file and ONLY append new data to for example: ip_all.txt?

Like I have in ip.txt

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
```

and in ip_all.txt

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
```

then apache make logrotate, so access files are empty then

ip.txt

```
empty
```

ip_all.txt still contain

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
```

then after few minutes
ip.txt

```
5.5.5.5
6.6.6.6
```

and then ip_all.txt

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
5.5.5.5
6.6.6.6
```

or how to make this easier ?

Comment: appending new IPs to a temporary file and then `cat oldips newips | sort -u > ips` might work but would become increasingly inefficient and I'd probably instead put them into a sqlite database

Comment: Yep, database..